# Spree Commerce Bootstrap Frontend installation fails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, spree

I'm trying to install spree_boostrap_frontend (I've tried both with 2-2-stable and master) on my spree 2.2.1 and I get the following error when I try to load the web site:

> couldn't find file 'spree/frontend/spree_bootstrap' (in
>   /home/vagrant/mystore/vendor/assets/javascripts/spree/frontend/all.js:13)

Extracted source (around line #10):

```
   <%= favicon_link_tag image_path('favicon.ico') %>
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'spree/frontend/all', :media => 'screen' %>
   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
   **<%= javascript_include_tag 'spree/frontend/all' %>**
   <!--[if lt IE 9]>
     <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.6/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
   <![endif]-->
```

(**) line #10 is the one between the double *

Any idea on how to solve it? I also tried to uninstall the gem but the problem still persists (probably I've installed in the wrong way? I've just commented the corresponding line in the Gemfile and then re-ran bundle install)

Answer (score -1):

Delete these lines:

```
//= require spree/frontend/spree_bootstrap
```

from `vendor/assets/javascripts/spree/frontend/all.css`

```
*= require spree/frontend/spree_bootstrap
```

from `vendor/assets/stylesheet/spree/frontend/all.js`